# Cannot connect to PayPal API via cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to set up PayPal Express Payment via the "Classic" NVP API.

Trying to connect from my server to the PayPal-Sandbox using cURL, the connection stalls and times out after about 2 minutes.

I'm using the [example call](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout) from the docs:

```
curl -v --insecure  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp  -d  "USER=platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com&PWD=1255077037&SIGNATURE=Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html"
```

Shell output is:

```
* About to connect() to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
* Trying 173.0.82.83... Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

When I try to do this via PHP `curl` I don't get any errors and simply an empty resource handle.

I can easily do the requests (and get the correct data back) from my local machine and from other servers that I can access so I guess this is some server side misconfiguration going on. Not being a server person I am a little clueless.

cURL is enabled and logs the following in `phpinfo`:

```
libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
```

openSSL is enabled as well. Also, I'm having the same issues when trying to connect to the live version of the API.

Comment: Maybe there's some firewall rule on your server blocking these requests, are you able to access with curl other websites from this server? what about other HTTPS websites?

Comment: Thanks, strangely I can easily use curl for other domains, including `https` connections.

Comment: look at the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936733/timeout-on-connecting-to-https they are all related to an outbound firewall restriction.. and someone even mentions paypal :)

Comment: Thanks, do I need to contact the provider to find out about these settings or can I somehow do this on my own?

Comment: shouldn't `USER=platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com` be `@gmail.com`?! not sure if this is the problem though

Comment: if you have good server support I would open a ticket about it, if not, try to figure out which firewall you have installed and then google how to see active rules. maybe you'll get some hint from your cpanel and likes

Comment: @razzak: That's what it says in the PayPal API docs. Usually the usernames seem to formatted like `{{username}}_api1.{{domain.com}}` - also it's working fine like this and returns `ACK=success` from other machines.

Comment: @talkol: Yeah, I just wrote them an email, let's see what they say. Wasn't too successful using Google yet. Thanks for your input!

Comment: if you have root access, you can also run `tcpdump` and "sniff" the communication between the servers to see what's wrong. see this http://www.alexonlinux.com/tcpdump-for-dummies

Comment: (I'm with PayPal) yes, the API user is fine as-is. I agree with everything @talkol said.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert since you're with PayPal `:P` may I ask you a related side question: All the english docs use a sandboxed API endpoint using an `api-3t.` prefix whereas the german documentation tells me to just use a prefix of `api.`. Is there any difference? Thanks!

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301987/why-are-my-dodirectpayment-calls-ignored/17871400#17871400

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ch = curl_init();
# Merchant Account Credentials
$ppUserID = "User Id Email"; //Take it from sandbox dashboard for test mode or take it from paypal.com account in production mode, help: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/
$ppPass = "User Pass"; //Take it from sandbox dashboard for test mode or take it from paypal.com account in production mode, help: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/
$ppSign = "Paypal Sign"; //Take it from sandbox dashboard for test mode or take it from paypal.com account in production mode, help: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

$ppAppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T"; //if it is sandbox then app id is always: APP-80W284485P519543T

$paypal_header_options = array();
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: $ppUserID";
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: $ppPass";
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: $ppSign";
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV";
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV";
    $paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: $ppAppID";

$URL = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp'
    .'?USER='.$ppUserID
    .'&PWD='.$ppPass
.'&SIGNATURE='.$ppSign
    .'&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout' 
    .'&VERSION=93'
    .'&RETURNURL=https://localhost/express-checkout-single-product/success.php?success=true'
    .'&CANCELURL=https://localhost/express-checkout-single-product/index.php'
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD'
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=250.00'    #The payment amount for the first receiver   # Merchant(Primary AC) Account Amount
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=225.00'                         # Merchant(Primary AC) Account Email
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=25.00'    #Receiver designation (there can be only 1 primary receiver)
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order' 
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=email' 
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART110-PAYMENT0'    #The payment amount for the second receiver   # Seller(Secondry AC) Account Amount
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=USD'
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=75.00'    #The payment amount for the first receiver    # Merchant(Primary AC) Account Amount
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=65.00'                          # Merchant(Primary AC) Account Email
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=10.00'    #Receiver designation (there can be only 1 primary receiver)
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Order' 
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=email' 
.'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART110-PAYMENT1' 
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Departs2'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Sunset'
.'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=125'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=15'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Departs'
.'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=100.00'
    .'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT1=10.00';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $paypal_header_options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $paypal_response = curl_exec($ch);

$responseAr = explode('&', $paypal_response);
$parsedResponseAr = array();
foreach($responseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode('=', $value);
    if(!empty($tmpAr))
        $parsedResponseAr[strtoupper($tmpAr[0])] = urldecode($tmpAr[1]);
}
print_r(json_encode($parsedResponseAr));
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

A) First try to `wget  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` and see if you can get a simple connection with "Bad Request" reply , and if not you have been blocked by Paypal server or your firewall is blocking you on port 443 to access paypal

B) try to add custom header: `-H "Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"`

`curl -v --insecure  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp  -d  "USER=platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com&PWD=1255077037&SIGNATURE=Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html" -H "Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"`

C) what version of CURL and on what platform are you using? I have:

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably The PayPal Express Payment service **stop/cut** your connection because of the **wrong authentication** or **not valid ssl certificate issued**. In this case, try to ask the service provider about this issue.

Hopefully, solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to your server's version of nss package and api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com using an SNI certificate. You can verify it by executing

`openssl s_client -servername api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com -tlsextdebug -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 2>/dev/null | grep "server name"`

over bash. The output is `TLS server extension "server name" (id=0), len=0` which indicates that this server is with SNI certificate.

The solution is actually simple.

**For RedHat variants :**

```
sudo yum -y update nss*
```

**For Debian variants :**

```
sudo apt-get update nss*
```

You don't really have to change your code( for connection wise problems)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have enabled ICMP Traffic in my server right now curl and get working perfectly.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT; iptables -F OUTPUT
```