# Why are my DoDirectPayment calls ignored?

Tags: paypal

I've been sending DoDirectPayment calls to PayPal for years with no problem and recently I've had periods of an hour or more where these calls don't get answered by PayPal and after about four minutes the cURL software that sent the call times out and generates the error:

```
            DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7)
```

Then suddenly, after an hour or more of no customers being able to make a payment, and without me doing anything on my end, the calls start getting answered again by PayPal and people can again make payments.

It acts like the PayPal server gets overloaded and drops requests.  Then when their load goes down they start answering all their requests again.

The $API_Endpoint the cURL is using is https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp.
The version of the PayPal protocol I'm using is 95.0.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what might be going on?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of anyone else reporting any issues similar to this.  A couple of things that you may want to check into is with your hosting provider to make sure they were not having any type of network and check [PayPal's Site Status](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus) pages to see if there were any outages or updates going on at the times you experienced the issues, as they could of caused the issues you are seeing.

Comment: If you Google "Paypal connect error 7" you'll see that people all over the internet are having this problem. PayPal's response is that  you need to show us in a trace route that the request got to PayPal before we can help you. One suggestion from PP was that the shared server we're on could be running out of sockets so can't make the cURL call. Anyway, the effort now is to work with our hosting provider to generate  trace route and possibly see some sign that the server ran out of sockets.   We'll see . . .

Comment: There were some issues with going to the AT&T network recently, you could check to see if you are going through their network and if its getting blocked.

Comment: Here's an update.  The tracert idea is a dud.  tracert is just some ICMP packets and It turns out that many routers and servers don't respond to ICMP. So all you find with a tracert is the first node in the path that doesn't respond to ICMP. One thing that would help is to know where the PayPal servers are physically.  Then I could perhaps move the site to a hosting provider that was physically close to PayPal and hopefully avoid the bad node.